# Update bool value in a jsonb column - jsonb_set

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

With the following json exemple:

```
{
  "red": false,
  "blue": false,
  "yellow": false
}
```

I have to update one of the elements to true and the expected result is:

```
{
  "red": false,
  "blue": false,
  "yellow": true
}
```

First, i tried to update this way:

```
UPDATE table_name
   SET jsonb_column_name = jsonb_set(jsonb_column_name, '{yellow}', ('"true"')::jsonb, true)
```

But the result was

```
{
  "red": false,
  "blue": false,
  "yellow": "true"
}
```

not what i want, its a string, not bool

Also tried:

```
UPDATE table_name
   SET jsonb_column_name = jsonb_set(jsonb_column_name, '{yellow}', true, true)
```

But i got an error, that makes sense, the 3rd parameter has to be jsonb

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function jsonb_set(jsonb, unknown, boolean, boolean) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

And i cannot make true::jsonb because bool cant be cast to jsonb:

```
SQL Error [42846]: ERROR: cannot cast type boolean to jsonb
```

Ther is another way to do this? no need to use jsonb_set, i think i can user str_replace an then convert to jsonb but i don't know if its safe

Comment: did you try `'true' :: jsonb` ? `UPDATE table_name SET jsonb_column_name = jsonb_set(jsonb_column_name, '{yellow}', 'true' :: jsonb, true)`

Comment: @EdouardH.: That should be an answer.

Comment: yes, it works, thanks, you can post this as answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need `jsonb_set` for this example. As this is a `jsonb`column, you can simply append the new value and the existing key/value pair will be replaced with the new one.

```
update table_name
   set jsonb_column_name = jsonb_column_name || '{"yellow": true}';
```

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to Edouard answer, i realized that i hadn't tested all the obvious possibilities.

`'true'::jsonb` with just sigle quotes worked

```
UPDATE table_name
   SET jsonb_column_name = jsonb_set(jsonb_column_name, '{yellow}', 'true'::jsonb, true)
```

Comment: You don't need the 'true'::jsonb, you can put it just as 'true'

Comment: You could also use the to_jsonb function and not have to worry about manually constructing sql strings