# Update single element in jsonb column with sqlalchemy core

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a jsonb column in a table, where each element is of the form

`{id: str, value: bool}`

I'd like to update a single (or list of) element(s) matching an ID. Is there an idiomatic way to do so using sqlalchemy **core** (not ORM), without reading and writing the whole column, or constructing sql queries by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69771172/5320906), given this initial setup:

```py
tbl = sa.Table(
    't71821876',
    sa.MetaData(),
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
    sa.Column('stuff', JSONB),
)

tbl.drop(engine, checkfirst=True)
tbl.create(engine)

with engine.begin() as conn:
    ins = tbl.insert()
    conn.execute(
        ins, [{'stuff': {'id': str(n), 'value': False}} for n in range(3)]
    )
```

We can do the update with `jsonb_set`* like this:

```py
with engine.begin() as conn:
    stmt = (
        sa.update(tbl)
        .where(tbl.c.stuff['id'].astext == '0')
        .values(
            stuff=sa.func.jsonb_set(tbl.c.stuff, '{value}', json.dumps(True))
        )
    )
    conn.execute(stmt)
```

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69771275/5320906) on that page could be translated to

```py
with engine.begin() as conn:
    stmt = (
        sa.update(tbl)
        .where(tbl.c.stuff['id'].astext == '1')
        .values(stuff=tbl.c.stuff + json.dumps({'id': '1', 'value': True}))
    )
    conn.execute(stmt)
```

but it replaces the column in the selected row(s) so presumably does not meet your criteria.

---

* [Postgresql JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-json.html)